# Can I take an air pistol out of Israel into Ghana?

Tags: air-travel, israel, ghana

A friend has gifted me an air pistol while on holiday in Israel and would like to take it back home to Ghana with me. Can I take it out of Israel an how do I do that? I have checked with the Authorities in Ghana and I can import it.

Comment: Have you checked with the airline?

Comment: Have you checked with Ghanaian customs?   What law exists in Ghana regulating air pistols?  Are they allowed?  Do you need a licence/training etc.  Do you have the necessary paperwork?  Have you checked that you can take it from Israel?  For that matter do you need a end user certificate?

Answer (score 2):

#### Partial answer for the Israeli side of things:

I don't use guns myself, but I consulted [The AirSoft factory](http://bbguns.co.il/), a BB-gun/air-gun store in Israel. They told me the following:

You need an official approval from the ministry for the economy to take an air-gun out of Israel. To do so, you contact them, give them the item's serial number (and probably more details), and they contact the customs at the airport to let you through when you get there. I've been told that *at the minimum* this takes 2 weeks - and even that if you're willing to pester them every day, otherwise it'll be longer. Also I'm not sure whether or not you'll need a written approval from them. I mean, I was told you won't, but I wouldn't trust that. Israel is rather uptight about security.